# Recommended Java Concurrency/Parallelism Library for SMS Sender System

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, sms

In our company we are building a high demand system for sending SMS to different clients and providers through SMPP and also directly using modems.

The system handles different requests, and connects to a database to select messages and update their status (sent, received, error etc). We receive demands for sending SMS that are queued according to priorities, and released by different channels according to what is requested. Right now, is necessary to generate threads to handle the different channels concurrently, but this makes the system run slow as the transactions can be numerous.

We are interested in develop a new system, that should not have too many problems with concurrency and that would maximize the capacity to take advantage of our server processors.

To our understanding, our problems could be solved remaking the system with a different handling of threads for the requests, 
¿Which architecture, framework or library would you recommend for handling this problem, which will provide the best performance?

We are currently considering: Java 7 Fork/Join, IBIS (MPJ, GMI, Satin) and AKKA (Actors library), but it is not a limitation. Is also desirable that the system is not tied to the architecture, and may be scalable and migrated to a cloud service.

PD: The current system does generate one thread per message to send, and use somehow thread pools, but not at all in an optimized way. Apart from improving that poor implementation we would like something to improve the overall performance taking advantage of all our resources (cores, processors).

Comment: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki Akka as perfect as well

Comment: Did my answer help you dude? If so then please accept it with the checkbox and upvote if you can.

Comment: I upvoted it, it did not solve my doubt, but it has good points thought.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now, is necessary to generate threads to handle the different channels concurrently, but this makes the system run slow as the transactions can be numerous.

The implicate in this statement is that it is the threads that is making the system slow and not the transaction bandwidth.  What is your evidence about this?

The only way threads could create problems is if there were so many of them that you were running into memory issues and the system was slow because of GC overhead.  Each thread allocates a large contiguous stack space (by default 512k) so 2000 threads (for example) will consume 1gb of core.

One way to verify that the threads *are* the problem is to watch the memory usage of your application using jconsole or something.  If all of your memory buckets are full and the GC button does little to nothing then you are correct.  Another thing to try is to use fixed sized thread-pools instead of forking a thread for each request you get.  If this improves your system performance, but decreases your transaction throughput then you are correct.

Since the SMPP protocol seems to be TCP/IP, you don't want all of your threads to be sitting in wait loops.  Writing your own SMPP protocol using NIO is possible if you know your NIO fu.

I'd also do some [searches for java NIO SMPP](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20NIO%20SMPP) libraries.  A quick search took me to [JSMPP](http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/).  I have no experience with it however.

> JSMPP is a java implementation (SMPP API) of SMPP protocol (currently support SMPP v3.4). It provides interfaces to communicate with Message Center or ESME (External Short Message Entity) and able to handle traffic 3000-5000 messages per second.

Comment: That's Insightful, I will check with the Jconsole, although as I can see in the code the threads are most likely the problem. We do are using JSMPP, so far is the best SMPP library we have found. 
Why do you think if we are having problems with threads, Java 7 Fork/Join is not a solution?

Comment: You say "the only way threads could create problems is if there were so many of them that you were running into memory issues", but i don't think that's true. Threads don't just use memory, they are units of scheduling in the operating system; using lots of threads will lead to lots of context switching, which has a performance cost.

Comment: Threads consume stack space memory @Tom which defaults to 512k per thread so lots of threads do add up.  2000 threads uses 1gb of memory for example.  Also, the context switching is a myth.  There is a lot of performance data which shows that context-switching cost is minimal.  For example, it is hard to thrash a JVM these days.  Now creating GC load because of high memory, that's the real issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell JSMPP uses classic Java IO, not NIO, and only supports a 1 thread per sender model.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp

Twitter's NIO SMPP library built on Netty. Currently used to support hundreds of operator binds `sending/receiving` billions of messages per month. Solves the problem of needing a thread per `bind/message`. There are examples of how to use it in `cloudhopper-smpp/src/test/java/com/cloudhopper/smpp/demo/`